# Avatar is not getting uploaded using paperclip and aws-sdk gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a problem with my avatar upload. It worked once for me but I must be blind this time.
I am using paperclip and aws-sdk gem and [set up everything as described here.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

I have tested it with 2 buckets. One with the standard `us-location` and one with the `eu-west-1` location. **Neither is working.**

Here is all my related code:

#### config/s3.yml

```
development:
  bucket: ***
  access_key_id: ***  
  secret_access_key: ***
test:
  bucket: ***
  access_key_id: ***  
  secret_access_key: ***
production:
  bucket: ***
  access_key_id: ***  
  secret_access_key: ***
```

#### app/model/art.rb

```
class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at, :description, :name, :avatar
  has_attached_file :avatar,
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
      :url => ':set_alias_url',
      :path => "/:style/:id/:filename.:extension",
          :bucket => '***'

end
```

#### app/controller/arts_controller.rb

```
class ArtsController < ApplicationController 
...
def create
      @art = Art.new(params[:art])
      if @art.save
          flash[:notice] = "sucessfully saved upload" 
          redirect_to arts_path
      else 
          flash[:notice] = "error" 
          render "new"
      end

    ...
```

#### app/views/arts/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Arts#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/arts/new.html.erb</p>
<%= form_for(@art, :url => arts_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %> <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :name %> <br/>

    <%= f.label :description %> <br/>
    <%= f.text_field :description %> <br/>

    <%= f.label :avatar %> <br/>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %> <br/>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I searched the web for 2 days now but I cannot find my error. Here is the response from the server:

```
POST "/arts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-19 12:11:39 +0100
    Processing by ArtsController#new as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZyZFfSaTl9CQpL5kOXyt/rcoi+SCuNp5/deCYda83sE=", "art"=>{"name"=>"asdf", 
"description"=>"asdf", 
"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000296e0b8 @original_filename="lakritz10.jpg", 
@content_type="image/jpeg", 
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"art[avatar]\"; filename=\"lakritz10.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20121219-5804-1rnvkmj>>}, 
"commit"=>"Create Art
```

So can anyone help me to fix this?

thanks in advance.

EDIT: It seems like even without an attachment that nothing is getting saved in the database. Thats wired...

EDIT_SOLUTION: In order to solve my particular problem I had to change the `routes.rb`
I previously assumed that the entry

```
match "arts/new", :to => "arts#new", :as => 'arts'
```

would do the job. This was not the case. 
I had to change the line into:

```
resources :arts
```

Because i do not understand how routes exactly work yet, I cannot explain it.

Comment: what params are being passed upon submission of your form, check in your console

Comment: Ok, it was a routing problem. I changed my route for arts to resources  :arts and now everything works perfect. I guess I have to learn how routes work and how to manually add put/get/match routes. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @schnika.  Please add your solution as an answer so this doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
match "arts/new", :to => "arts#new", :as => 'arts'
```

only creates a route to the `new` action. It maps `arts_path` to `arts/new` which is then the target of your form. You really need to submit the form to `arts#create` which is what the resource does automatically for a `POST` with a new object.